# SharePoint 2013 workflow issue, not able to publish

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

When trying to publish SharePoint 2013 workflow facing "Errors were found when compiling the workflow"

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAs

How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is to use a domain certificate instead of self-signed certificate. To do that we need to ensure “Active Directory Certificate Services” role is deployed in one server within the domain.
>
> If “Active Directory Certificate Services” is available we can use following steps to request a domain certificate
>
> **1) In App Server go to Microsoft Management Console and add snap-in for Certificates**
>   [image]
>
> **2)Select computer account**
>   [image]
>
> [image]
>
> **3) Navigate to Personal > Certificates**
>   [image]
>
> **4) Click Request new certificate**
>   [image]
>
> **5) Use this certificate for workflow manager configuration**

## Source: [Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel–multi server environment with self-signed certificate for SharePoint 2013 workflow manager](http://dinushaonline.blogspot.se/2014/05/could-not-establish-trust-relationship.html)

Comment: How to use new certificate to configure workflow manager which is already configured?

Comment: refer this
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658589.aspx